# testing existing pages with mocha-phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm not quite getting how to use PhantomJS and Mocha together, specifically through  [mocha-phantomjs](https://github.com/metaskills/mocha-phantomjs).

I've read some tutorials (the one at [tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-javascript-with-phantomjs--net-28243) is quite helpful) and am not seeing how I can test external pages using Phantom and Mocha.  I'm sure I just need a nudge.

In the tutorial the author creates a tests.js file with some DOM setup/manipulation, as well as some mocha assertions.  Then, he creates a separate HTML file that loads the tests.js file and uses mocha-phantomjs to fire up phantom and run the tests.

That's where I'm a little confused, how the `mochaPhantomJS.run()` method actually does things behind the scenes, whether it knows to search the js file for a `describe` block and run all tests within, that sort of thing.  I don't need chapter and verse, but a high-level summary would be ideal.

Also, if I want to test an outside page, how can I best do that?  In the tutorial all the DOM investigation and testing is done on the test page.  If I want to test a different page, do I change or setup my assertions differently?  Should I call the PhantomJS API from those tests and point to an external site?

Answer (score 2):

Mocha will run tests that have been specified in javascript that has been included in the html page that is launched. If you look at the example html page on [mocha-phantomjs](https://github.com/nathanboktae/mocha-phantomjs) it expects the test definitions using describe/it calls to be in the `test/mycode.js` file. If you put something like

These tests are only testing what is in the main file and associated javascript, there isn't anything special that mocha-phantomjs provides to test external html files. If you want to test your own html files I think you can head in a couple of directions, I came up with these:

**first option**: Create a way to load the parts of you app that you want to test into the main testing html file. How to do this depends a lot on your application setup. It is probably well-suited for a modular system. Just include the javascript from your application and test it. Not so good for full-page-html tests.

**second option**: Open new windows with the pages to test from the main testing html file (from within phantom that is). You can open a page using `window.open()` just like a normal browser. I created a proof of concept like this:

```
describe('hello web', function () {
        it('world', function (done) {
            var windowReference = window.open("fileundertest.html");

            // windowReference.onload didn't work for me, so I resorted to this solution
            var intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
                if (windowReference.document && windowReference.document.readyState === 'complete') {
                    window.clearInterval(intervalId);
                    expect(windowReference.document.title).to.equal("File Under Test");
                    done();
                } else {
                    console.log('not ready yet');
                }
            }, 10);
        });
    }
)
```

This solution is relatively simple, but has the same drawbacks as any page-loading solution: you never know when the page is fully initialized and have to resort to some sort of timeout/wait system to wait for the page to get into the correct state. If you want to test a lot of separate html files these delays start to add up. Additionally waiting for 'onload' on the page that I opened wouldn't work so I created my own function based on setInterval and a (non-perfect) test on the document that was being loaded. I found out there are differences in behavior between loading an html page from the filesystem and loading the same page via a web-server.

**third option**: Create a mocha test that you run nodejs-style from the command line, and launch phantomjs with a specific page as part of your mocha tests. This is what I'd say you need if your system really depends on html pages that are quite different from each other.

I quickly tested the third option, here is my test based on the example I found on the [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) page (which is an alternative solution to [phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs) that is used by mocha-phantomjs -- I've used neither for more than brief experiments so I cannot recommend which one to use)

```
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai'),
    phantom = require('phantom');

var expect = chai.expect;

describe('hello node', function () {
        it('world', function (done) {
            phantom.create(function (ph) {
                ph.createPage(function (page) {
                    page.open("http://www.google.com", function (status) {
                        console.log("opened google? ", status);
                        page.evaluate(function () { return document.title; }, function (result) {
                            console.log('Page title is ' + result);
                            ph.exit();
                            expect(result).to.equal("Google");
                            done();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });

        });
    }
)
```

While it is possible to test this way I'd say that maybe the overhead of the communication between the code in the phantom-world and the testing code in the nodejs world isn't worth it. You can of course move a lot of general functionality to a couple of helper functions, but you are still stuck with having to call `page.evaluate()` to perform specific tests on the page. The same issues with timeouts/waits as above apply.

As an aside: do already know [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/)? Maybe it can be helpful for your setup should you choose to build something on 'plain' phantomjs.